# side way table in double column paper format

Tags: formatting, two-column, landscape, supertabular

I use the following code in single column format, and it gives the following output: [image: output in single column]

```
     \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\begin{document}

     \begin{sidewaystable*}[!htbp]
\caption{the caption here}
\label{tabRes}
\centering
{\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllllllllll}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column 1} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column 2} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column column 3} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{Scolumn column 4} & \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}}{column column column column 5  }  \\ 
      \cmidrule(l){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}\cmidrule(l){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
                       & H         & F        & H        & F       & H        & F       & H       & F       & H        & F  \\ \hline
\% ABCDEFGHIJ          & 0.11      & 3.2      & -18.3    & -1.2    & 22       & 11.15   & 8.5     & 0.8     & 202      & 8.11      \\ 
V1                     & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.5  & 1.3-2.2  & 1-2     & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.5 & 0.7-2.6 & 0.6-1.7 & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.6   \\ 
V2                     & 0.05-0.7 & 0.08-0.9 & 0.05-0.6 & 0.1-0.6 & 0.05-0.7 & 0.1-0.4 & 0.1-0.7 & 0.2-0.6 & 0.05-0.5 & 0.08-0.8   \\ 
R1                     & 2222     & 88       & 888      & 99992   & 11       & 222     & 3333    & 4444    & 111      & 666        \\ 
R2                     & 22 k     & 888 k    & 98 k     & 888 k   & 111 k    & 55555 M & 54 k    & 888 k   & 11.5 K   & 111.4 K     \\
B1                     & 2222     & 88       & 888      & 99992   & 11       & 222     & 3333    & 4444    & 111      & 666          \\ 

& & & & & & & & &{\small($R=$\SI{3.5}{\kilo\ohm})} &{\small($R=$\SI{7}{\kilo\ohm})} \\
P1 & 49 & 32.4     & 42.6     & 42      & 323.8    & 28.7    & 33.5    & 31.63   & 41.5     & 31            \\ 

 & & & & &{\small($I1=$\SI{2}{\micro\ampere})} &{\small($I2=$\SI{1}{\micro\ampere})} & & &  & \\ \hline

{\small$^a$ For i1 0-\SI{0.1}{\micro\ampere}.}      \\
{\small$^b$ At i2 \SI{0.2}{\micro\ampere}.}        \\


\end{tabularx}
}
\end{sidewaystable*}
 \end{document}
```

I need the same output in Double column format. However i get the following output:[image]

,while using the same code except fore "supertabular" instead of "tabularx"

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable*}[!htbp]
\caption{caption here}
\label{tabRes}
\centering
{\small
\begin{supertabular}{lllllllllll}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column 1} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column 2} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column column 3} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{Scolumn column 4} & \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}}{column column column column 5  }  \\ 
      \cmidrule(l){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}\cmidrule(l){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
                           & H         & F        & H        & F       & H        & F       & H       & F       & H        & F  \\ \hline
\% ABCDEFGHIJ          & 0.11      & 3.2      & -18.3    & -1.2    & 22       & 11.15   & 8.5     & 0.8     & 202      & 8.11      \\ 
V1                         & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.5  & 1.3-2.2  & 1-2     & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.5 & 0.7-2.6 & 0.6-1.7 & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.6   \\ 
V2                     & 0.05-0.7 & 0.08-0.9 & 0.05-0.6 & 0.1-0.6 & 0.05-0.7 & 0.1-0.4 & 0.1-0.7 & 0.2-0.6 & 0.05-0.5 & 0.08-0.8   \\ 
R1                         & 2222     & 88       & 888      & 99992   & 11       & 222     & 3333    & 4444    & 111      & 666        \\ 
R2                         & 22 k     & 888 k    & 98 k     & 888 k   & 111 k    & 55555 M & 54 k    & 888 k   & 11.5 K   & 111.4 K     \\
B1                     & 2222     & 88       & 888      & 99992   & 11       & 222     & 3333    & 4444    & 111      & 666          \\ 

& & & & & & & & &{\small($R=$\SI{3.5}{\kilo\ohm})} &{\small($R=$\SI{7}{\kilo\ohm})} \\
P1 & 49 & 32.4     & 42.6     & 42      & 323.8    & 28.7    & 33.5    & 31.63   & 41.5     & 31            \\ 

 & & & & &{\small($I1=$\SI{2}{\micro\ampere})} &{\small($I2=$\SI{1}{\micro\ampere})} & & &  & \\ \hline

{\small$^a$ For i1 0-\SI{0.1}{\micro\ampere}.}      \\
{\small$^b$ At i2 \SI{0.2}{\micro\ampere}.}        \\



\end{supertabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable*}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Your second piece of code does not compile. It shows error messages in the line of, `Undefined control sequence ... \SI`, `Undefined control sequence....\kilo`. Don't you need to make it sure that the code compiles and people will feel interested to contribute?

Comment: I edited it, "\usepackage{siunitx}" was missing.

Comment: As I understand, are you trying to put a double column table in a two column document?

Comment: I need to put a multi column table "which is shown in fig1" in a double column document.

Comment: It works by moving the code in another place in the document!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}

% For putting the float in the first page, comment out if the float is
% not needed in the first page
\usepackage{stfloats}
% For dummy text, delete this
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htbp]
  \caption{caption here}
  \label{tabRes}
  \centering
  {\small
    \begin{supertabular}{lllllllllll}
      \hline
      & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column 1} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column 2} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{column column 3} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{Scolumn column 4} & \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}}{column column column column 5  }  \\ 
      \cmidrule(l){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}\cmidrule(l){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
      & H         & F        & H        & F       & H        & F       & H       & F       & H        & F  \\ \hline
      \% ABCDEFGHIJ          & 0.11      & 3.2      & -18.3    & -1.2    & 22       & 11.15   & 8.5     & 0.8     & 202      & 8.11      \\ 
      V1                         & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.5  & 1.3-2.2  & 1-2     & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.5 & 0.7-2.6 & 0.6-1.7 & 0.6-1    & 0.5-1.6   \\ 
      V2                     & 0.05-0.7 & 0.08-0.9 & 0.05-0.6 & 0.1-0.6 & 0.05-0.7 & 0.1-0.4 & 0.1-0.7 & 0.2-0.6 & 0.05-0.5 & 0.08-0.8   \\ 
      R1                         & 2222     & 88       & 888      & 99992   & 11       & 222     & 3333    & 4444    & 111      & 666        \\ 
      R2                         & 22 k     & 888 k    & 98 k     & 888 k   & 111 k    & 55555 M & 54 k    & 888 k   & 11.5 K   & 111.4 K     \\
      B1                     & 2222     & 88       & 888      & 99992   & 11       & 222     & 3333    & 4444    & 111      & 666          \\ 

      & & & & & & & & &{\small($R=$\SI{3.5}{\kilo\ohm})} &{\small($R=$\SI{7}{\kilo\ohm})} \\
      P1 & 49 & 32.4     & 42.6     & 42      & 323.8    & 28.7    & 33.5    & 31.63   & 41.5     & 31            \\ 

      & & & & &{\small($I1=$\SI{2}{\micro\ampere})} &{\small($I2=$\SI{1}{\micro\ampere})} & & &  & \\ \hline

      {\small$^a$ For i1 0-\SI{0.1}{\micro\ampere}.}      \\
      {\small$^b$ At i2 \SI{0.2}{\micro\ampere}.}        \\



    \end{supertabular}
  }
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-10]


\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: this code not giving me the output shown in your picture, this column  `& & & & & & & & &{\small($R=$\SI{3.5}{\kilo\ohm})} &{\small($R=$\SI{7}{\kilo\ohm})} \\ `is left shifted. and this column is 
      `P1 & 49 & 32.4     & 42.6     & 42      & 323.8    & 28.7    & 33.5    & 31.63   & 41.5     & 31   \\ ` is right shifted

Comment: I simply compiled it and posted a screenshot. Were you careful in copy-paste? Which LaTeX compiler are you using?

Comment: I use MikTEX compiler.

Comment: I don't think that I can be of much assistance here. I double checked, the output is flawless in my computer. Moreover, I *did not* change your tabular even a single dot.

Comment: Actually i tried it in a new document it works well, however while using the same code inside my original document that have the same packages Some shifting happens.

Comment: Also, different cells shifting appears in the same document  for the same code  as i past it in different sections?!